# Getting error while running the ionic cross platform project on xcode

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, cross-platform, xcode8

I am new to ionic cross-platform while running the ionic cross platform app for generating build I am facing following error.

> DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file:
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C234C014-5541-45C9-96A9-4D7B3E0AA4FA/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
>   2016-10-15 14:55:26.568 HelloWorld[363:42830] Unbalanced calls to
>   begin/end appearance transitions for .
>   2016-10-15 14:55:26.591 HelloWorld[363:42906] [FATAL] [WL_INIT]
>   -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:174 :: Init failure: Can't read checksum.js, The file name is invalid., (null). Reinstall the
>   application and try again.

I used MFP SDK(plugin)

So guys kindly give some suggestion for taking build

Its is just a helloworld program with MPF SDK.

Downloaded the sample project generated by ionic [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxaG5uDuG79HUDJ3SUM0Mk1ZSXM) with some bugs. bugs fixed code [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxaG5uDuG79Hdk9MYnhpc1RYWFk).

Comment: Did you try what the error suggested? 'Reinstall the application and try again.'

Comment: Yes Aurora000, I uninstall and tried but no use

Comment: 2016-10-15 14:55:26.432 HelloWorld[363:42830] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C234C014-5541-45C9-96A9-4D7B3E0AA4FA/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
2016-10-15 14:55:26.568 HelloWorld[363:42830] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x14ed59d90>.
2016-10-15 14:55:26.591 HelloWorld[363:42906] [FATAL] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:174 :: Init failure: Can't read checksum.js, The file name is invalid., (null). Reinstall the application and try again.

Comment: Used MFP SDK(plugin)

Comment: The information you've provided is not helpful. You need to provide your full implementation of the app so it could be debugged, and the steps you've followed. Mention which ionic version you're using... and again, the actual project so it could be debugged.

Comment: Idan Adar, its is just a helloworld project with MPF SDK, the ionic version 2.1.0. And Can i share the source code with you?

Comment: Upload the project to google drive or Dropbox

Comment: Uploaded on Google Drive. With bugs generated by ionic https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxaG5uDuG79HUDJ3SUM0Mk1ZSXM bug fixed https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxaG5uDuG79Hdk9MYnhpc1RYWFk

Comment: What do you mean bugs by ionic and bug fixed? Change the projects to be public so they could be downloaded....

Comment: While getting the iOS project from cross platform, some issue came. Sure let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125790/discussion-between-anand3777-and-idan-adar).

Comment: The links are still not useable! Make the links PUBLIC

Answer (score 1):

Since the links you've provided are of no use (the links lack permission to download.....), I suggest that you will follow these blog posts:

1. [Integrating MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 in Ionic-based apps](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/19/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic-based-apps/)
2. [Best Practices for building AngularJS apps with MobileFirst Foundation 8.0](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/11/best-practices-for-building-angularjs-apps-with-mobilefirst-foundation-8.0/)

Here is the basic premise:

1. Install the following CLIs

   npm install -g mfpdev-cli
   npm install -g cordova ionic
   npm install -g cordova
2. Create a New Ionic Project

   ionic start myApp blank

   Ionic automatically adds the **Cordova iOS v3.8** plug-in, however MobileFirst Foundation v8.0 support **Cordova iOS v4.0 and above**. To overcome this, remove the iOS platform and re-add it. Change directory into your Ionic project and run:

   ionic platform remove ios
   ionic platform add ios@latest

   If you want to add the android platform, you can add it with:

   ionic platform add android@latest
3. Add the MobileFirst Cordova SDK

   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp

   You can confirm the installed plug-ins by entering `ionic plugin list`
4. Update Ionic Code

   Open the **js/app.js** file.

   The module is named **starter**.

   angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

   The **ng-app** directive in the **index.html** file tells angular which code to run on the page.

   To link the view and the model of the app together, **create a controller** in the **app.js** file.

   .controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
   })

   The `$scope` service allows you to share variables and functions from the controller to the view.

   Go back to **index.html**.

   Add **ng-controller** to the body tag and include the mainCtrl name. This allows you to use the controller anywhere inside the body tag.

   ng-controller="mainCtrl"
5. Register App on MobileFirst Server

   To enable the MobileFirst capabilities such as using the Mobile Browser Simulator to preview the application we need to add some JavaScript code to connect to the MobileFirst Server.

   Open **app.js** and enter the following at the bottom:

   ```
    function wlCommonInit() {
   console.log(">> wlCommonInit() ..." );  
   var serverUrl = WL.App.getServerUrl(function(success){
       console.log(success);
   }, function(fail){
       console.log(fail);
   });
   WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(
       function (accessToken) {
         console.log(">> Success - Connected to MobileFirst Server");          
       },
       function (error) {
         console.log(">> Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server");  
         console.log(error);        
       }
   );
   ```

   };
6. Register your app with your MobileFirst Server.

   mfpdev app register

Comment: Idan Adar sorry for the delay, the shared link is now access able you can try now, at the mean time i will check the above link.